# How do I programmatically get the usable page height in a Word document/template

Tags: c#, ms-word

My software copies graphs into a Word document, and the document is based on various templates that users have made, therefore the usable page height varies, depending on header/footer and margins. I'm trying to optimize the graph height and there may be 2-3 graphs per page, depending on the report type.

I've tried using the Range.PageSetup.PageHeight property and subtracting the Range.PageSetup.TopMargin, Range.PageSetup.BottomMargin, Range.PageSetup.HeaderDistance, and Range.PageSetup.FooterDistance, but the calculation seems to be missing something, i.e. the returned graph height is a little too big or small to fit the number of graphs per pg. I realize it depends when this calculation is done in the code, since the formatting may be adjusted, so the calculation is done just prior to coping the graph.

Comment: welcome to StackOverflow, please add more detail about your code.

Comment: This is a problem that's more complex than the first appearance. Header and footer heights can be expanded by content that's in them, and their interior margins then will overlap the nominal distances for top and bottom margins, reducing the effective page size. It's also possible for text boxes in the header or footer to move the effective margins if they have text wrapping applied. This is a common practice to make the first page of a Word document have different margins that the others.

Comment: This is of concern, except that at the time the code is ready to copy the graphs, the document headers/footers/margins are all set. Its not just a template anymore, but a live Word document capable of being edited and saved.